# Anti-forgery token issue

Tags: asp.net, post, antiforgerytoken

I have a form on my page which is defined like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "signupform" }))
            {

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ..... FORM MARKUP
}
```

My page is RegistrationForm.

Controller definitions:

```
public ActionResult RegistrationForm()
        {
           //custom logic            
            return View("RegistrationForm", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RegistrationForm(RegisterFormRenderingModel model)
        {
             ... cutom logic
              return View("RegistrationForm", model);
        }
```

This works fine. I can submit the form and everything works. But on that page there is a modal the user can login and gets redirected back to the same page. The authentication is done through a third party system and then when the user is authenticated they get redirected back to the same page as before. 
When that happens we get the error "The required anti-forgery form field '__RequestVerificationToken' is not present.". The post does work properly.

Any thoughts on what is wrong here?

Comment: I assume your page is RegistrationForm, because you have not defined a controller in the form and it still works ? By redirecting are you referring to `return View("RegistrationForm", model);` ?

Comment: that is correct. RegistrationForm is my page

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load a new token and the whole page again by properly redirecting, for example, instead of `return View("RegistrationForm", model);` in the post-registration part, use `return RedirectToAction("Index");` (assuming index-action is the default).

**EDIT**

First of all, why is the antiforgerytoken populated in the login page, where there is no user to protect ? If there is no proper reason, you shouldn't be bothered with the problem in the first place.

Besides of that, you should check how the redirection is implemented from the auth provider. You can check this for example using Chrome's network tools and see is it a 307 redirect as post or a 302 Get or something else (?)

Does everything work peachy, if you hard refresh the page on browser after authentication (Ctrl+F5) ?

Comment: in my case I have an SSO happening so a third party system is doing authentication and returning back to the page. Not sure how that would apply in this case?

Comment: So the authentication provider returns to page and this is when the problem occurs?  Your question does not seem to provide all the necessary information.

Comment: edited the question. Hopefully this is more clear now

Comment: Edited my answer.